# Force Close on new activity start from button press

Tags: android, android-activity, android-xml

Trying to have a button open a new activity. My xml for the button looks like this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="viewStyle"

        />
```

My button function looks like this:

```
public void viewStyle(View view) {
        // launch new brewery page class
        Intent i = new Intent(this, BreweryPage.class);
        i.putExtra("myBeerObject",  e);   
        i.setClass(this, StylePage.class);
        startActivity(i); 
     }
```

My stylePage.java looks like this:

```
public class StylePage extends Activity {
    BeerData e;
    //get beer details from bundle
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.brewery_page);

        //get data from listview
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        e = b.getParcelable("myBeerObject");

        //show title
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.styleTitle);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.styleDescription);

        //show description
        tv1.setText(e.beerStyle); 
        tv2.setText(e.beerStyleDescription); 
    }

}
```

My error is a null pointer exception:

```
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.beerportfoliopro/com.example.beerportfoliopro.StylePage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.StylePage.onCreate(StylePage.java:28)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-20 22:33:48.210: E/AndroidRuntime(29904):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
```

Comment: @StinePike of which file?

Comment: tv1.setText(e.beerStyle);

Comment: @Mike you can check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

From you logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.beerportfoliopro.StylePage.onCreate(StylePage.java:28)
```

It clearly tells that you have a `nullpointerexception` at the `line 28` in `oncreate` method in the `StypePage` class within the `com.example.beerportfoliopro` package

And as you said the line 28 is

```
tv1.setText(e.beerStyle);
```

So it seems the tv1 is null. or e is null.

tv1 can only be null after this line

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.styleTitle);
```

So may be you are inflating the textView with wrong id. Check your layout xml and see if you are inflating correct id.

And e can be null in this line

```
e = b.getParcelable("myBeerObject");
```

So your getparcelable is returning null..

So the problem is either in the above two cases. Check those two.

( all is just a guess)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on StinePike's answer, the other possibility is that `e` is null, which would be caused by getParseable. According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelable%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the value associated with the given key, or null if no mapping
>   of the desired type exists for the given key or a null value is
>   explicitly associated with the key.

Are you sure you are passing your `myBeerObject` object?

Answer (score 1):

You should debug and watch your e variable to see if it's still null after the call to  `e = b.getParcelable("myBeerObject");`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, its late and I must be tired because this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.brewery_page);
```

which sets the content view for my style page should not read brewer_page and should actually be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.style_page);
```

Never program when your tired.....

Comment: many people offered good advice, pls be kind and upvote them, the least they can expect

Answer (score 0):

You have to used this way.

**BeerData class implements Seralizable**

```
public class BeerData implements Serializable {
//put your varible with getter settter method
 }
```

remove `setClass` statement.

```
public void viewStyle(View view) {
        // launch new brewery page class
        Intent i = new Intent(this, StylePage.class);
        i.putExtra("myBeerObject",  e);   
         startActivity(i); 
     }
```

in **StylePage.class**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    e=(BeerData ) i.getSerializableExtra("myBeerObject");
    //here print data and see what happen
```

If you find trouble then put comment.